# How can I use applescript to target an embedded sidebar button in a menu bar application?

Tags: applescript, menu-bar

I can access a menu bar application via applescript doing something like:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "NordVPN" to ¬
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click
        get menu items of menu 1 # menu 1 doesn't exist
    end tell
```

But the menu bar application (NordVPN) I want to target isn't using simple menu bar items. Is it possible to target the button in the following hierarchy using applescript? It looks like it's embedded in a popover and tableview. I want to automate clicking a button (NordVPN.SidebarButtonCell) in this hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used automator to record the action and this allowed me to generate the following script which contains the path to the UI element:

```
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process \"NordVPN\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “p2p” button.
delay 1.616678
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click UI Element \"p2p\" of UI Element 1 of row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of UI Element 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process \"NordVPN\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

so the relevant snippet is:

```
click UI Element \"p2p\" of UI Element 1 of row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of UI Element 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process \"NordVPN\"
```